# java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'

Tags: java, controller, response, resttemplate

I'm obviously missing something but I don't know what...
It's stupid how much little things make you go crazy more than complicate ones...

**This is the controller's code:**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getClienteNomeCognome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> getClienteNomeCognome(@RequestParam("nomeCliente") String nomeCliente,
        @RequestParam("cognomeCliente") String cognomeCliente) {
    List<Object> listaRisultati = new ArrayList<Object>();
    try {
        listaRisultati = serviziDocumentaleService.getClienteNomeCognome(nomeCliente, cognomeCliente);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn(String.format("Errore inatteso sulla chiamata del servizio: [%s]", e.toString()));
    }
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Avvio ricerca cliente con nome: %s, cognome: %s)", nomeCliente, cognomeCliente));
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Object>>(listaRisultati, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**And this is getClienteNomeCognome:**

```
    public List<Object> getClienteNomeCognome(String nome, String cognome) throws Exception {
    try {
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String url = "somelink?cognome=%25"+cognome+"%25&nome=%25"+nome+"%25";
        final ResponseEntity<List> response = (ResponseEntity<List>) restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class);
        if (response.getBody() != null && response.getBody().toString().contains("<error>")) {
            throw new Exception(String.format(
                    "La risposta del servizio contiene degli errori: %s",
                    response.getBody()));
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug("Fine chiamata al servizio di ricerca cliente");
            return response.getBody();
        }
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
        throw new Exception(String.format(
                "Errore durante la chiamata. Error: %s",
                hcee.getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(String.format(
                "Errore generico durante la chiamata al servizio. Error: %s"
                        + e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: Did not tried it. Nevertheless, the problem might be `[%s]` part and especially the square brackets. Try to remove or escape them.

Comment: pretty sure your logger supports format as well and you don't need to use `String.format`. E.g. `LOGGER.warn("Errore inatteso sulla chiamata del servizio: [{}]", e);` Your error btw complains that there is a %s without a thing to put in its place

Comment: your provided code ran fine on my computer. So may be the error comes from your method getClienteNomeCognome.
Furthermore, LOGGER have its way to format String without using String.format. For example: `LOGGER.info("Test {}", nomeClient);`

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace such that we can better look where is the problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
throw new Exception(String.format("Errore generico durante la chiamata al servizio. Error: %s" + e.getMessage()));

should be

throw new Exception(String.format("Errore generico durante la chiamata al servizio. Error: %s", e.getMessage()));
```

Comment: This did the job! Thank you!

Comment: Shocking I had the same typo!

Comment: Hard to spot typo:  There's a  `+` at the end of the format string, it should be a comma (`,`)

Answer (score 2):

I can't be 100% sure of the issue, since its missing code so I can emulate it from here. But it looks like:

```
LOGGER.info(String.format("Avvio ricerca cliente con nome: %s, cognome: %s)", nomeCliente, cognomeCliente));
```

has an extra `)` after the last `%s`, so maybe its just not reading it correctly? Unless that's just a mistake when copy-pasting the code here.

Let us know if that works.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of that typo but that's not the problem :)

Comment: That's all right. Does your compiler at least give you the line number where the error is?